# Are there any free web hosts that allow adult content?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, free, adult-content

I'm looking for a free web hosting (PHP) provider, that permits adult content.

And by adult content, I don't mean videos. At most, photos. And I can keep it non-nude. I just want to display information about pr0n-stars.

If I keep it non-nude, but still contain information about pr0n-stars, do you think 000webhost will allow this?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Hey @John Conde, I really looked at that question, and couldn't find my answer there. Please help me in this, is there an answer to this question? And if so, please tell me where.

Comment: Did you email 000webhost. How are we supposed to answer a question that only they can answer since it's their company, service, and server? Email them. Email all free hosts and ask them exactly what you've asked above.

Comment: I thought it was a good idea to take my chance to find people that may already done this. Ok, will do what you said, thanks.